# Confusion with shared variables in React

Tags: reactjs

The "Bad button" only works once, since it's not controlling the same "value" as the "Good button". What am I missing here?

```
const Test = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  const [view, setView] = useState()

  const add = () => setValue(value + 1)

  const badButton = () => {
      return (
          <div>
              <button onClick={add}>Bad button</button>
          </div>
      )
  }
  return (
      <div>
          {value}
          <button onClick={add}>Good button</button>
          {view}
          <button onClick={() => setView(badButton)}>show bad button</button>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Thanks for replying, I'm going to use the flag method as suggested. But I would still like to know why the two buttons don't work the same way in this original case.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-goldstine-tbwic) 
I feel it's the right way to handle such a usecase. Instead of storing component itself in state. I replaced it with a boolean. By default it will be false and badButton will be hidden, on click of showBadButton, i'm setting the view state true and bad button will come into picture. Actually Its a good buton now. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `view` as a flag to show/hide `BadButton` component, I have created a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gdrunr) that showcase the following code snippet:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

const Test = () => {

  const [value, setValue] = useState(0)
  const [view, setView] = useState(false)

  const add = () => setValue(value + 1)

  const BadButton = () => {
      return (
        <button onClick={add}>Bad button</button>
      )
  }

  return (
      <>
          {value}
          <button onClick={add}>Good button</button>
          {view ? BadButton() : null}
          <button onClick={() => setView(!view)}>
            {view ? 'hide' : 'show'} bad button
          </button>
      </>
  )
}

render(<Test />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Welcome to StackOverflow